# Line chart shows all available data series in gray, need to colorize only selected series and only display these in legend

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I would appreciate help creating a macro that will colorize selected data series from a list and only display these in the legend for this chart:

[image]

From the list of 19 constituents, I would like to number the selected series 1 - 5 so that up to five series can be shown in color among the gray non-selected series.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59163794/edit) to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need VBA to do that. This can be done entirely in the worksheet. Conceptually:

- create five data validation cells where people can select the (up to ) five data series
- use formulas next to these five cells to look up the data for that series from your main chart data source. This will create a range with five rows of data that is the same shape as your chart source data
- add these additional rows to the chart and format the lines with colors. Use the series order to determine which lines sit on top of others.
- remove the original grey data series from the legend.

Now the user can select different constituents and the selected ones will be plotted in color, their names will be in the legend and the rest of the chart remains grey.

Answer (score 0):

In [Using Worksheet Controls to Highlight Selected Data in an Excel Chart](https://peltiertech.com/interactive-controls-to-highlight-selected-data-in-an-excel-chart/) I show how to construct a chart with lots of gray series, and use listboxes to select which series to display in color. No VBA, just worksheet formulas.

[image: Line Chart with Selectively Highlighted Series]